# Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script. `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-sass

Version detials:
node v12.16.3
npm v6.14.4
node-sass 4.12.0

Error starts with logged message:

*Binary has a problem: Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by xyzPath/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node)*

further logs: 
*npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.*